# Programmatically adding ABOVE to LayoutParams causes view height to be 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view

I have a custom `View`. In the constructor for the view, I create and add two subviews. However, using `LayoutParams.addRule()` is causing some problems. Rules such as `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` work, but when I try to use `ABOVE`, the subview ends up with a height of 0.

Here is the code in my constructor:

```
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(width, height);
    mLayoutParams.leftMargin = left;
    mLayoutParams.topMargin = top;

    mImage = new ImageView(getContext());
    mImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image_drawable));
    mImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    mImage.setId(R.id.my_image_id);
    addView(mImage, mLayoutParams);

    mText = new TextView(getContext());
    mText.setText(R.string.my_text);
    mText.setId(R.id.my_text_id);
    LayoutParams textParams = new LayoutParams(200, 40);
    // textParams.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL, TRUE); //Works
    textParams.addRule(ABOVE, mImage.getId()); //Doesn't work

    addView(mText, textParams);
```

If I inspect the view on an emulator with the Device Monitor, I can see that the `layout_height` of the text is 40, but the top, bottom, and height parameters are all 0. `measuredHeight` appears to be the same as the screen width.

1. Am I doing something wrong with adding the rules?
2. Is there a better place to add the rules? Does something need to happen first?
3. Any other alternatives? Making the `TextView` have a height of FILL_PARENT, gravity BOTTOM, and setting its bottom margin to the height of the image works, but I need to be able to add another view above the text, and this won't work for that.

Comment: Try adding a rule for your `Image` to be `Below` your `TextView`. When things are added to a `RelativeLayout` they are added to the top-left unless otherwise specified. I think what might be happening is there is no place above your `Image` for the `TextView` to go

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that in my code. `mLayoutParams` has a left, top, width, and height defined. Shouldn't that be enough for it to know where to go? @codeMagic, I've updated the code.

Comment: Adding `ALIGN_BOTTOM` to `mImage` doesn't change anything. If I change it to `BELOW` instead, I get a circular dependency error. I want the text to be above the image, and the image has a fixed location.

Comment: You get circular dependency error because you didn't remove the rule from your `TextView` that says `Above`. Its kind of like saying "you stand to the right of me and I will stand to the left of you"...where do we start? Remove that and you should be good

Comment: Good point, but it still doesn't help. I have a set of coordinates that I want for the image, and the text should be above that. I don't know where to put the text if I don't fix the image at that location.

Comment: If you do it the original way you had it and change `width` and `height` of the `TextView` does it change anything? Also, you might try laying it out in a graphical editor and see what params you need to make it work. I will try to look a little more in a bit when I have a minute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36749/discussion-between-karl-and-codemagic)

Answer (score 1):

where in your code are you checking for height?  If it's somewhere within onCreate or onCreateView, you won't get any info. Layout is a two-pass process and in those two methods the two passes are not complete.

You may need to get the height in those methods by using the ".post" method like this:

```
        myView.post( new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                int height = myView.getHeight();
            } 
        });
```

The runnable makes it run on the UI thread, but it's invoked after both passes, the measure pass and the layout pass, have completed. So trying to set a rule based on a center horizontal without first knowing the measurements is going to fail.

Comment: The width and height params used for the image are passed in from somewhere else, and I've verified that they are non-zero and correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
mText = new TextView(getContext());
mText.setText(R.string.my_text);
mText.setId(R.id.my_text_id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 40);
// textParams.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL, TRUE); //Works
textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, mImage.getId()); //Doesn't work

addView(mText, textParams);
```